# How does Facebook search work?

Tags: facebook

More specifically, what factors determine the priorities they assign in response to a given query?  I'm looking for answers that address numerous scenarios including queries that...

1. Specify the "type" of result (objects such as users, posts, pages, etc. or connections like friendships, likes, tags, etc.),
2. Have [authentication tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#auth) as well as ones that don't.
3. Have conditionals such as "since" and "until."
4. Don't even specify a type, such as this search for the word [query](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY).

Comment: After some tinkering, I found that queries of the fourth type tend to return very recently created/updated objects, suggesting that perhaps Facebook just returns the most recently edited results relevant to the query. Still open to insight, confirmation, or discussion.

Comment: I've done more tinkering with queries of the fourth type.  The responses are definitely in decreasing created/updated times, although I haven't determined which one is the primary key.

Comment: I also compared the responses I received with the ones that I could with _the same query_ at the [Facebook API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).  __The responses were not the same.__

Comment: Case study:  searches for popular words ("love" or "hope") return different results where the objects are a few seconds apart from each other.  A specific search ("mad scientist") resulted in objects that were 30 days older than those returned to the Explorer.  But then a general search ("mad") returns objects made almost two days _ahead_ of the explorer's results!

Answer (score 0):

I am actually working on an app that uses /search to search places and I use a bit of all scenarios. I couldn't write down a specific order they appear in and to be honest I highly doubt it's something as easy.

I'm 99% sure it works like the Search in Facebook does, using the user data to bring up the most relevant results. I live in Ireland for 2 years now, but while testing the app I constantly receive search results from Romania and actually close to my Hometown, which are relevant to me.

Regarding your observations, Facebook's algorithms might take into account the source of the request as well - which would be good, means it only improves as your app gets more users.